# Normal curveture on a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I have an exercise:
Find the normal curvature of the Viviani curve on the sphere
$$r = R[\text{sin}ue(v)+\text{cos}(uk)]$$
at any point and at points along the **z** axis

legend:
$$r=\phi(v)e(u) + \psi(v)k$$
$$z=\psi(v), y=\phi(v)$$

This problem is from a book on differential geometry. I don't know how to solve it and have no one to ask.

Comment: I am having trouble parsing your equations. e.g. $\sin\! ue(v)+\cos(uk)$. What are scalars and what are vectors in the equations?

Comment: Start over with proper notation. What is the Viviani curve? And what is *normal curvature* on a sphere?

Comment: @robjohn I have no idea. I hoped it is well-known for differential masters.
Ted Shifrin: I know Viviani curve. Can you share any link for normal curvature on a sphere? Or on any other surface?

Comment: I have been a differential geometer for 45 years, so that's close enough to "master." Your question makes zero sense. I know what Viviani's curve is, too, but not everyone does. But on a sphere, the normal curvature is the same at every point in every direction (see, for example, section 2 of chapter 2 of my differential geometry text, which you can download for free from the link in my profile), so the curve is totally irrelevant. Based on your question, the book you're trying to read is not a good choice for self-study.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you. I had the same feeling but I thought I'm just too stupid for it and don't know some obvious laws.

Comment: If this is literally how the question is writing in the book, the book is hopeless. But, seriously, maybe mine will help you learn better.